# For unknown reason, a button click closes my window. How can I fix this?

Tags: monodevelop, gtk#

I am trying to replicate a simple addition of 2 entries with a button in Monodevelop (shown how to make it step-by-step) but somehow the window closes 2 seconds after pressing the button without actually changing anything.

The code for the button:

```
using Gtk;
using Frontend.ChatService;

public partial class MainWindow : Gtk.Window
{
    public MainWindow() : base(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel)
    {
        Build();
    }

    protected void OnDeleteEvent(object sender, DeleteEventArgs a)
    {
        Application.Quit();
        a.RetVal = true;
    }

    protected void OnButton1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ChatService client = new ChatService();
        int x = Int32.Parse(entry1.Text);
        int y = Int32.Parse(entry2.Text);
        int sum = client.Add(x, y);
        entry1.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
}
```

And the sum (which I tested and think works):

```
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace Backend
{
    public class ChatService : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public int Add(int x, int y)
        {
            return x + y;
        }
    }
}
```

I left the main file program.cs as generated and is:

```
using System;
using Gtk;

namespace Frontend
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Application.Init();
            MainWindow win = new MainWindow();
            win.Show();
            Application.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

The window does pop up as it should and shows no problem until the button is pressed.

Edit:
I forgot to run the backend / server part, which is why the function was not found... (beginners mistake I guess)
Works now

Comment: Any exceptions logged in the Application Output console? I take it you're running in debug mode on the client?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that your code throws an exception you are not aware of. The problem is in the code that handles the button being clicked.

```
protected void OnButton1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChatService client = new ChatService();
    int x = Int32.Parse(entry1.Text);
    int y = Int32.Parse(entry2.Text);
    int sum = client.Add(x, y);
    entry1.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Let's go line by line:

```
ChatService client = new ChatService();
```

Here you are creating a new instance of what it seems to be a system service or maybe a web services. This could throw if the service is not known (in the former case), or if the connection is interrupted or does not reach a destination, etc., in the latter case.

These lines are also delicate:

```
int x = Int32.Parse(entry1.Text);
int y = Int32.Parse(entry2.Text);
```

They will throw in case the field `entry1` or `entry2` are empty, or contain a letter...

In order to manage these cases you need to add `try... catch` blocks in the appropriate places. Alternately, you can use Int32.TryParse.

For example, assuming the service is in the web:

```
protected void OnButton1Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChatService client;
    int x;
    int y;

    try {
        client = new ChatService();
    } catch(HttpRequestException exc) {
        client = null;

        var dlg = new Gtk.MessageDialog(
                            this,
                            Gtk.DialogFlags.Modal,
                            Gtk.MessageType.Error,
                            Gtk.ButtonsType.Ok,
                            "Connection error"
         );

        dlg.Text = exc.Message;
        dlg.Run();
        dlg.Destroy();
    }

    if ( client != null ) {
        if ( !int.TryParse( entry1.Text, out x) {
            entry1.Text = "0";
            x = 0;
        }

        if ( !int.TryParse( entry2.Text, out y) {
            entry2.Text = "0";
            y = 0;
        }

        int sum = client.Add(x, y);
        entry1.Text = sum.ToString();
    }
}
```

Getting code which correctly handles errors is always harder, of course.
Hope this helps.